# Angular UI Grid how to show multiple fields for the single column

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using [**Angular Ui Grid**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid).How can I show multiple fields for the single column ? Thanks.

I need to show both `streetNumber` and `StreetName` on the same column.How can I do that ?

```
vm.propertyListGridOptions = {
                appScopeProvider: vm,
                flatEntityAccess: false,
                fastWatch: true,
                showHeader: false,
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        name: app.localize('IplNumber'),
                        field: 'id',
                        width: 100,
                    },
                    {
                        name: app.localize('BrAddress'),
                        field: 'address.streetNumber',
                        width: 140,
                    }

                ],
                data: []
            };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom template like this

```
$scope.gridOptions['columnDefs'] = [

    {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
    {field: 'options',displayName: 'Options', cellTemplate: '<span>{{row.entity.streetNumber}} {{row.entity.StreetName}}</span>'}
];
```

You can also refer this page for documentation for custom templates http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates

Comment: Its sorting and filtering based on the `options` mentioned by `field` attribute. But how do I filter exactly how the data appear ?